# What had Darth Sidious planned for Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-sidious

In "The Clone Wars" Series 5, Episode 16 (The Lawless), Darth Sidious defeats Darth Maul in battle and tells him he has "other plans" for him.

What were these plans?

Comment: wasn't the dude cut in half and dead in a shaft by then?

Comment: @Oldcat he survived miracously, thanks to the dark side, driven insane and on the brink of death, and was later salvaged by his brother and a witch from Dathomir

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Darth Maul's story continues in [Son of Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir) comics from 2014, a follow-up to unused Clone Wars cartoon storyline from season six (the episodes weren't finished before the season was cancelled halfway). Sidious' plan was to

> to draw out Mother Talzin, leader of the Nightsisters, so she can be destroyed as a potential threat to the eventual Sith rule of the galaxy.

Talzin was a Dathomir witch, mother of Darth Maul. Her being poweful, and the fact that she and Sidious had a little bit of history, he wanted her dead.

> The plan involved letting Maul escape and have him lead them to Talzin.

The story is part of The Clone Wars Legacy line.

Comment: when did that comic come out? (aka is it part of the new canon?)

Comment: Does he still become a [giant metal spider monster](http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120518041057/starwars/images/5/57/DarthScorpionKing-SWE.png) in the comics? I know he did in the Clone Wars show.

Comment: @InguShama the comic is a direct follow-up to the cartoon, so yeah, before that, he was the spider thingy that creeped me the hell out. I've added info

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it was never disclosed. But I would guess that he wanted him as some sort of dark agent or maybe as a backup in case his plan for Anakin Skywalker fell through.

Comment: It was disclosed in the follow-up comics. "Son of Dathomir"

Comment: Sry I was on talking canon. I hadn't finished studying the legacy part.

Comment: "Son of Dathomir" *is* canon.

Comment: Sry, I haven't finished my research into the Clone Wars. My expertise is in the Old Republic era.